# Get access token via Log in with google in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I would like to be able to login with my google account in my unity game.

I've tried using Play Game Services, which imo would be the best solution, and I can log in and get name and ID and stuff, but I can't get the access token used, so I can verify who the user is on my server.

I have a server with a lot of player-data, that I can't put in Game Services, so I need to verify it's the correct user, and the ID is not safe enough.

How can I log in with google and get an access token in unity?

cheers

Comment: You can try this asset store package. Works just fine for iOS & Android and you can extend it for web if u need to. Additionally play games services for iOS is deprecated long back. https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/94517

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to get token :

```
PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Authenticate(success =>
{
    if (success)
    {
        Debug.Log("Token :");
        Debug.LogFormat("{0}", PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.GetAccessToken());
        Debug.Log("End Of Token");
    }  
});
```

But you have to add a client id to your Google play services unity plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've added the Client id in the android config, but PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.GetAccessToken() is still empty - do you know of anything else I might need to do?

Comment: You need to link a Web app and then add web Client id not the android app client id. note that it takes a while to get token from server and sometimes the first time you call GetAccessToken() it prints nothing .

Comment: Hi, I believe I have this similar issue, but I thought the Callback was meant to fix this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37214979/google-play-services-with-unity3d-token

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried writing a custom Android plugin for your game?
You could get anything in your Unity game that you would be able to on a native Android app, and then pass that data to reference against your server.

They have pretty straightforward documentation for it:
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html

I hope that helps!

Edit: Elaborated statement.

Comment: Thanks - I've considered that, but I just wanted to know if anybody else had build one or knew of one that I could use before I started on that;o) Maybe I should just get cracking on that instead of sitting, staring on this topic...

Comment: @smokiespartakus I've used google+ login tokens before, and can tell you it's easier to work with than a lot of other APIs! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.GetToken() will give you a string token, but can take a while to download, even several seconds. If the app setup is correct, it should populate after a while. Keep polling it whether it's null or empty, and it should eventually yield a valid token. The token is only good for 1 hour.

Comment: I tried to do this using an IEnumerator and a while loop checking whether the access token was null or not, but access token constantly stayed null, even after I waited for 5 minutes:

Answer (score 0):

In order to access Google APIs on a backend web server on behalf of the current player, you need to get an authentication code from the client application and pass this to your web server application. This code can then be exchanged for an access token to make calls to the various APIs. For more details on this flow see: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow

To get the Auth code: 1. Configure the web client Id of the web application linked to your game in the Play Game Console. 2. Call PlayGamesPlatform.GetServerAuthCode() to get the code. 3. Pass this code to your server application.

I am able to get the AuthCode and this code is given to the server and they generate the access token and authenticate my account.