# Google Play Services with Unity3D Token

Tags: amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-services

I am using google play games services with Unity 3D. Whenever I run the game on my android phone (samsung s7) I am able to login, and authenticate the user, and it returns successfully. the app logs in just like any other released game (like clash of clans). However, I need to get the ID Token. this token ends up being blank on return. I am not sure if i have a settings issues, or a configuration issue, but the token never comes back correctly. What might be the issue?

I have tried variations of this, gone over the docs, and I have google play services set up, android, and web OAuth2 Credentials set up. I have gone to Windows > Google Play Services > Android and set up the configurations to match what is on the git site (https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity)

**May or may not be relevant:**

The only thing that I DO have setup that i am not actively using (which im not sure where to place this) is a ServiceAccount. but this may be a different issue entirely, because im trying to integrate to amazon too.

**NOTE:**

> the services say Social.PlayerInfo.... etc. and i have tried variations of this, and PlayGamesPlatform. I know playGamesPlatform works correctly on authentication, it is just not returning the token.

**Google Play Service Version Using** 0.9.32

**Unity Version:** 5.3.1f

**Code Snippet:**

```
public void GoogleAuthenticates(Action callback = null) {
    PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Authenticate((bool success) => {
        if(success) { //this works just fine.
            Debug.Log("Successfully Logged in!");
            PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.GetIdToken((token) => {
            //The token is blank :(
            CognitoIdentitySync.AddGoogleTokenToCognito(token);
            }
        } else
            Debug.Log("Login Failed!");
        _isGoogleLoggedIn = success;
        if(callback != null)
            callback.Invoke();
    });
}
```